# Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Currently I want to implement Redux to my function, so it will be stored inside the initialstate. In order to do so, I have to use a dispatch method which call the action inside the function. So the expected result is that I can dispatch the response.data.results with Redux, so based on that result I could add a like button on each image. But that is a problem that will be solved later on, for now I want to refactor the code so the function will dispatch the data based on the keywords or letter that has been submitted. But the console.log shows the error:

> Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

```js
  onSearchSubmit = async term => {  
    return(dispatch) => {
      const response = await unsplash.get('/search/photos', {
        params:{ query: term },
        //use the path on unsplash for image searching
      });
      
      dispatch(fetchImages(response.data.results));
      // this.setState({ images: response.data.results });
    }
    
  }

  render() {
    return (<div className="ui container" style={{marginTop:'10px'}}> 
      <SearchBar onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit}/>
      {/* <ImageList images={this.state.images}/> */}
    </div>);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return(dispatch) => {
  const response = await unsplash.get('/search/photos', {
    params:{ query: term },
```

You’re returning a non-async function and calling await inside it. Try making it async:

```
return async (dispatch) => {
  const response = await unsplash.get('/search/photos', {
    params:{ query: term },
```

Answer (score 0):

The `await` your error is referring to is in the anonymous lambda function `(dispatch) => {...` NOT `onSearchSubmit`.  Make that lambda async and everything should be fine.